# WPF Print RichTextBox as Image

Tags: c#, wpf, image, printing, richtextbox

I'm making an application in which I need to print a content of the wpf richtextbox to an **image**, my application requires *extremly* fast perfomance, so the solution which uses WinForms RichTextBoxPrintCtrl (my own class with Handle on the control itself) with overlay, works way too slow for me, is there any way i can make a printable(saving as an image, or renderable to Bitmap) wpf richtextobx?

Comment: Tried RenderTargetBitmap?

Comment: I don't know what to do, all this print methods can't see my scrollbar on richtextbox and print only a first part of it, but don't scroll it automatically to print all richtextbox

Answer (score 2):

check these links hope help :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.rendertargetbitmap.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/103184/How-to-Render-Bitmap-or-to-Print-a-Visual-in-WPF

http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2007/Sep/10/Rendering-a-WPF-Container-to-Bitmap